# Natural transformation defined by one element

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $C$ be a self-enriched category, a CCC, and $F : C \to C$ an endofunctor with strength, that is, $F$ comes with a natural transformation
$$st_{A,B} : A \times F B \to F (A \times B)$$
such that the "obvious" arrows commute (see nLab for tensorial strength).

I'd like to prove that the natural transformation $\alpha : Id \to F$ from the identity functor to $F$ must be defined by its action on $1$. I came up with a definition for $\alpha_A$:

$$\alpha_A = F \pi_1 \circ st_{A,1} \circ id \times \alpha_1 \circ \langle id , !_A \rangle$$

How can I prove that in fact this is an equality? Do I need to assume that $C$ is well-pointed? Is that enough?

Comment: You should ask the natural transformation to be a _strong_ natural transformation.

Comment: Even if $C$ is well-pointed?

Comment: Every functor $F:Set \to Set$ satisfies the property?

Comment: But every endofunctor on $\mathbf{Set}$ is strong, and every natural transformation between endofunctors on $\mathbf{Set}$ is strong.